# A riddle for your time (6)

Tags: riddle

```
I'm a cube with many different faces,
many look at me in despair.
I stay the same when i'm changed,
yet changing is what I do.
```

What am i?

Hint 1:

> I'm very colorful

Hint 2:

> I'm used by both children and adults for entertainment

Comment: Hi @WaleedAsim, when answering a riddle/puzzle please create a new answer rather than a comment, and utilise the spoiler block function by putting >! in front of your answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you:

> A Rubiks Cube?

I'm a cube with many different faces,

> A Rubiks cube has 6 sides but comprises of many smaller square "faces".

many look at me in despair.

> Rubiks cubes can be quite a maddening challenge.

I stay the same when i'm changed,

> No matter how much you twist and change it, it's still a Rubiks cube

yet changing is what I do.

> The aim of the puzzle is to change it.

Comment: There we go, perfect ;)

Comment: First thing I thought of :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A mirror?

*I'm a box with many different faces*

> When people look in a mirror it shows their face, and many different people can look at it.

*many look at me in despair*

> People often don't like the way they look, so would look upon themselves with despair, via the mirror.

*I stay the same when i'm changed, yet changing is what I do.*

> The mirror physically never changes, but the light it reflects and the images it shows does.

<s>Are you:</s>

> A six sided die?

*I'm a box with many different faces*

> A six sided die is a cube with a different number on each face.

*many look at me in despair*

> Dice are often used in gambling, where if they don't roll as intended, people can lose a lot of money and have a look of despair.

*I stay the same when i'm changed, yet changing is what I do.*

> As the die is rolled, the value (facing up) changes, but the die itself remains unchanged.

Comment: Good answer, not the one i was looking for though ;)

Comment: Have added a second answer :)

Comment: A "box" is a hollow container, so I dismissed the possibility of it being a die.

Comment: I love your updated answer @AHKieran still not the one i was thinking of though. Astralbee i didnt reference box as a hollow container in my answer. Ill replace the word box with a more appropriate word.

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A clock in a clock tower?

I'm a box with many different faces

> While a tower might not be a "box" shape, the housing for the clock is normally cuboid and contains the clock mechanism. A clocktower normally has 4 clock *faces*.

many look at me in despair.

> Perhaps because they are late? Or wishing that they could leave work sooner?

I stay the same when i'm changed,

> The time on a clock may be changed

yet changing is what I do.

> A clock changes by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A television

I'm a cube with many different faces

> A television changes "faces" by changing images on the screen

Many look at me in despair

> When people are sad they often stay at home and watch TV

I stay the same when I'm changed

> The TV itself doesn't change, it's just the programs and channels that do

Yet changing is what I do

> Watching the same channel and program over and over is not very fun

Hint 1

> TVs are full of colors

Hint 2

> Both adults and children watch TV for entertainment

Comment: I was going to say this too. Many different faces could also mean the actual faces on the television. And I look at the news with despair every single night.